# Python tkinter dynamic checkbutton method

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a settings page with lots of checkbuttons on it so I am trying to reduce the code but I am struggling when it comes to getting the checkbutton value to work so far I have:-

```
def _create_checkbox(self, label, index, state=0):
    x = label.replace(" ", "-").lower()
    self.settings_list[x] = state

    ttk.Label(self.settings_frame, text=label).grid(
        row=index, column=0)
    ttk.Checkbutton(
        self.settings_frame, variable=self.settings_list[x]
    ).grid(row=index, column=1)
```

the idea was to put the checkbutton names in a dict and then update the dict with the value but it is not working as planned, with my code all checkbutton values update as if they were one.

example list:

```
self.settings_list = {"force-gamemode": "0", "allow-cheats": "1"}
```

Edit to show minimal working example, I did originally  try to use variables (IntVar) but it failed (I cant remember why) but that's why I then switched to a dict:-

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("tkinter dynamic checkbox example")
        self.geometry("700x450")

        self.settings_list = {"force-gamemode": "0", "allow-cheats": "1"}

        self.settings_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.settings_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # create settings content
        self._create_checkbox("Force Gamemode", 0, 0)
        tk.Label(
            self.settings_frame, text="Label to show content between checkboxes"
        ).grid(row=1, column=0)
        self._create_checkbox("Allow Cheats", 2, 0)

        tk.Button(
            self.settings_frame,
            text="Create Properties File",
            command=self._create_properties,
        ).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew")

    def _create_checkbox(self, label, index, state=0):
        x = label.replace(" ", "-").lower()

        self.settings_list[x] = state
        ttk.Label(self.settings_frame, text=label).grid(
            row=index, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w"
        )
        ttk.Checkbutton(self.settings_frame, variable=self.settings_list[x]).grid(
            row=index, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w"
        )

    def _create_properties(self):
        print(self.settings_list["force-gamemode"])
        print(self.settings_list["allow-cheats"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. However, the problem is probably because you are not using a tkinter variable with the `variable` argument. The `variable` needs to be set to a tkinter variable such as `StringVar`, not a normal python variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you passed an integer 0 as the `textvariable` option of those `Checkbutton` widgets, an implicit `IntVar` will be created with name "0" for them.  Therefore they will be changed together because they share same tkinter variable.

You need to change

```py
self.settings_list[x] = state
```

to

```py
self.settings_list[x] = tk.IntVar(value=state)
```

inside `_create_checkbox()`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to acw1668's answer, to check the value

```
    def _create_properties(self):
        print(self.settings_list["force-gamemode"].get())
        print(self.settings_list["allow-cheats"].get())
```

so your code is ...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("tkinter dynamic checkbox example")
        self.geometry("700x450")
        self.settings_list = {"force-gamemode": "0", "allow-cheats": "0"}
        self.settings_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.settings_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # create settings content
        self._create_checkbox("Force Gamemode", 0, 0)
        tk.Label(self.settings_frame, text="Label to show content between checkboxes"
                 ).grid(row=1, column=0)
        self._create_checkbox("Allow Cheats", 2, 0)
        tk.Button(self.settings_frame, text="Create Properties File",
                  command=self._create_properties
                  ).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew")

    def _create_checkbox(self, label, index, state=0):
        x = label.replace(" ", "-").lower()
        self.settings_list[x] = tk.IntVar(value=state)
        ttk.Label(self.settings_frame, text=label
                  ).grid(row=index, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
        ttk.Checkbutton(self.settings_frame, variable=self.settings_list[x]
                        ).grid(row=index, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

    def _create_properties(self):
        print(self.settings_list["force-gamemode"].get())
        print(self.settings_list["allow-cheats"].get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, acw1668 answered first and I can only give the correct answer to one person